# Removing similar lines from two files

Tags: powershell, text-files, string-comparison

I'm trying to find a PowerShell solution to remove lines from file A that are similar in File B. `Compare-Object $A $B` does the comparing, but how to I go about deleting the items?

File A

```
yahoo.com
google.com
stackoverflow.com
facebook.com
twitter.com
```

File B

```
stackoverflow.com
facebook.com
```

**After Compare:** File A

```
yahoo.com
google.com
twitter.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the contents of file B from file A with something like this:

```
$ref = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\fileB.txt'

(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\fileA.txt') |
  ? { $ref -notcontains $_ } |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\fileA.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one line :

```
Get-Content 'FileA.txt','FileB.txt' | Group-Object | where-Object {$_.count -eq 1} | Foreach-object {$_.group[0]} | Set-Content 'FileC.txt'
```

or using aliases :

```
gc 'FileA.txt','FileB.txt' | Group | where {$_.count -eq 1} | % {$_.group[0]} | Set-Content 'FileC.txt'
```

First you get all the lines, then you group the same ones, you select the unique ones and put into a file.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell and simplicity, walk hand in hand, and I don't see simplicity in these answers. Your initial thought is correct: `Compare-Object` cmdlet is the way to go.

`diff $fileA $fileB | ? sideindicator -eq '<=' # v4`

The outcome can piped (or redirected) to a file.

Comment: Your solution is incomplete. `$fileA` and `$fileB` need to be the contents of the respective files, and (more importantly) you need to expand the `InputObject` property after the filter to get the desired output.