# Removing similar strings from csv using another csv

Tags: powershell, csv, string-comparison

I need to remove strings from one csv (file-a) that match or partially match the strings in another csv (file-b), based on the email address:

**file-a**

```
email,Firstname,Lastname 
Peter@hotmail.com,pete,Smith
Paul@gmail.com,paul,
Mary@hotmail.com,,Jones
puff@yahoo.com,puff,Dragon
```

**file-b**

```
email,Firstname,Lastname
Peter@hotmail.com,,Smith
Mary@hotmail.com,Mary
```

**deduped-output-file**

```
email,Firstname,Lastname 
Paul@gmail.com,paul,
puff@yahoo.com,puff,Dragon
```

I came across a similar question here:

[Removing similar lines from two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146379/removing-similar-lines-from-two-files)

However, this only works for exact matches, I tried using "notmatch" instead of "notcontains" but this did not work. I'm quite new to powershell and I can't quite figure out what I need to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code you attempted to use that didn't work quite as expected?

Comment: Hi, just seen your message, but I think the answer below has solved the issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first `Import-Csv` the files and use `Compare-Object` restricted to the property `email`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\02\28\SO_54929339.ps1

$fileA = Import-csv '.\file-a.csv'
$fileB = Import-csv '.\file-b.csv'

$deduped = Compare-Object -Ref $fileA -Diff $fileB -Property email -PassThru | 
  Where-Object Sideindicator -eq '<=' | 
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Sideindicator

$deduped 
$deduped | Export-Csv '.\deduped-output-file.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\02\28\SO_54929339.ps1

email          Firstname Lastname
-----          --------- ---------
Paul@gmail.com paul
puff@yahoo.com puff      Dragon
```