# How to remove a line, comparing two files using a partial string?

Tags: powershell

Im struggling to solve a problem in powershell.
I need to compare two files, and remove entire line from file A, based in string parts in file B. Lets say for example:

```
File A
Jeff is here.
Jhon is not.
Alice is coming.

File B
Jeff
Alice

Result
Jhon is not.
```

I tried a code using "foreach", but the things got to complex, so i tried a code more clean from other user:

```
$ref = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\fileB.txt'

(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\fileA.txt') |
  ? { $ref -notcontains $_ } |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\fileA.txt'
```

But got the same results, removing only if it matches exactly.

Comment: why does this not work?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146379/removing-similar-lines-from-two-files

Comment: It only removes the line if matchs the exactly sentence. For exemplo, I need to remove the line "Jeff is here.", based only in "Jeff" on the second file.

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick

```
$ref = Get-Content .\fileB.txt

foreach ($refLine in $ref) {
   (Get-Content .\fileA.txt) | ? { $_ -notmatch $refLine } | Set-Content .\fileA.txt
}
```

Downside is that atleast a single line must remain in fileA, otherwise it will leave one line that should have been removed.